# Need to find total sales of each date

Tags: powerbi

I'm stuck in finding total sales of a day, I need to further find out the % of each product in a particular date.
for eg: sales of beverages for 2/17/2018

[image]

Here I am trying to find the total sales for one particular date :
I am expecting 922 in the salesperday column.

Comment: can you share code for measure Sales?

Comment: sales = 
CURRENCY(SUMX('Sales_by_Store[1]',
    'Sales_by_Store[1]'[quantity_sold]*'Sales_by_Store[1]'[unit_price]))

Comment: This is SalesPerday =                                                                                     CALCULATE('Measure table'[sales],ALLEXCEPT('Calendar[1]','Calendar[1]'[Transaction_Date]))                                Sales works fine..Salesperday is not working correct when I use transactiondate.

Answer (score 0):

your table:

| Transaction_Date | product_group | sales | SalesPerday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2/17/2018 | Add-ons | $11.2 | $11.2 |
| 2/17/2018 | Beverages | $725.25 | $725.25 |
| 2/17/2018 | Food | $133.25 | $133.25 |
| 2/17/2018 | Merchandise | $24 | $24 |
| 2/17/2018 | Whole Bean/Teas | $28.95 | $28.95 |
| 2/18/2018 | Add-ons | $27.2 | $27.2 |
| 2/18/2018 | Beverages | $817.3 | $817.3 |
| 2/18/2018 | Food | $138 | $138 |
| 2/18/2018 | Merchandise | $54 | $54 |
| 2/18/2018 | Whole Bean/Teas | $178.18 | $178.18 |

you need to add  **Calculated Columns** for day with following formula:

```
Day = DAY('table'[Transaction_Date])
```

then you need SalePerDay measure

```
SalePerDay = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[sales]),ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[Day]))
```

at last create following measure for calculate percentage of product category per day

```
%Sale = SUM('Table'[sales])/[SalePerDay]
```

just aware of **implicit measure** and don't use them.